# Qt Removing a QGraphicsItem from QGraphicsScene with singleShot Timer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, graphics, signals-slots

While it is possible to automatically remove a QGraphicsTextItem from a scene using a timer and Qt's signal-slot mechanism like

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, QGraphicsTextItem*, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

other graphical objects (QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem) seem to not inherit QObject and as such cause an error when compiling:

> error: C2664: 'QTimer::singleShot': Konvertierung des Parameters 2 von
>   'QGraphicsEllipseItem *' in 'QObject *' nicht m”glich
>
> (conversion / cast of parameter 2 ... not possible)

Since I would like text and some graphics shown together for a limited time, my question is: 
How I can achieve automatic, timed removal of the above-mentioned 'other' objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem`s don't inherit `QObject` normally.  You would need to subclass `QGraphicsEllipseItem` like so:

```
class AutoHidingItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsEllipseItem 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // ...
}
```

Or you would simply have to have your scene keep track of the items to hide, and then hide it when it needs to. (Make a slot in your subclassed scene or view that hides or deletes the item.)

EDIT: @thuga pointed out that `QGraphicsEllipseItem` doesn't inherit `QObject`, while `QGraphicsTextItem` does already.  Edited answer to show this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: QGraphicsTextItem does inherit from QObject (QGraphicsObject). He wants to do the same for other graphics items like QGraphicsEllipseItem. Though your answer is correct, I just wanted to make it clearer.